# VTK Camera Clipping with 2 Renderers

Tags: c++, rendering, vtk

**Current Setup:**

- I have **2 renderers**, gridRenderer and  geoRenderer, within **2
  layers of a render window:**

```cpp
gridRenderer->SetLayer(0);
geoRenderer->SetLayer(1);
RenderWindow()->SetNumberOfLayers(2);
RenderWindow()->AddRenderer(geoRenderer);
RenderWindow()->AddRenderer(geoRenderer);
```

- I then connect their interactor by setting both of their active cameras to the same one:

```cpp
 gridRenderer->SetActiveCamera(geoRenderer->GetActiveCamera());
```

This successfully allows me to have a **grid in the background**, with a **geometry in the foreground**.

**Problem:**

- The camera's clipping planes only focused on the geoRenderer, causing the much larger gridRenderer's actor to be clipped out.

[image]

**Similar Issue:**

- https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/issues/17107
- The difference between my issue and this one is that I am updating both the gridRender's and geoRenderer's actors, **sometimes removing all of the actors within a renderer entirely** (empty renderer could mess up the clipping planes, not rendering anything, if the camera chooses it as the active renderer).
- My assumption is that VTK is confused as to which renderer to use in order to set the shared camera's clipping planes. I tried using `vtkRenderer::ResetCameraClippingRange()` on both of the renderer's but cannot get the clipping planes to form properly
- **Is there someway I can tell VTK which renderer to look at when resetting the clipping planes/camera?**

**Update:**

- I have begun to manually set the clipping range using a sum of
  `ComputeVisiblePropBounds` calls, along with disabling
  `vtkInteractorStyle::AutoAdjustCameraClippingRange` as such:

```cpp
double geoCB[6];
double gridCB[6];
geoRenderer->ComputeVisiblePropBounds(geoCB);
gridRenderer->ComputeVisiblePropBounds(gridCB);
double finalCB[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    // Even Index is Min
    if (geoCB[i] < gridCB[i]) {
      finalCB[i] = geoCB[i];
    } else {
      finalCB[i] = gridCB[i];
    }
  } else {
    // Odd Index is Max
    if (geoCB[i] > gridCB[i]) {
      finalCB[i] = geoCB[i];
    } else {
      finalCB[i] = gridCB[i];
    }
  }
}
geoRenderer->ResetCameraClippingRange(finalCB);
```

**Unfortunately this still does not work properly at all...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Important Update:**

- The above code is correct, you just need to call it every single time
  before `RenderWindow->Render()`.
- After creating my own implmementation of `vtkRenderWindow`, I simply needed to overrride `Render()`, putting the above code inside, and then finisihing the ovveride with a call to the default `Render()`
- If you simply set the min clipping planes to a very small value, and the max to a very large one, it might work but can destroy the depth filter, messing the whole render up completely.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can set the clipping range explicitly to large values with:
`vtkCamera.SetClippingRange(x0,x1)`

Comment: Took this, along with some other info, and updated post